# asset management - inventory and tagging

Tags: difficult-client, estimation, scope-of-work

I am needing a few quotes on a time estimate of manually tagging (stickers) and recording attributes of all fixed assets in an open, busy grocery store.

Client is refusing to pay because it wasn't completed within 5 hours. Tech was given an excel spreadsheet and told to manually tag every asset in the store and record the following attributes:
*Tag #
Tagged Date
Tagged By
Device Name
Location
Device Type (Dropdown)
Area (Dropdown)
Role (Dropdown)
Status (Dropdown)
Manufacturer
Model
Serial Num
Peripherals
Notes*

Can anyone help me out? This is approx 250 assets - almost all of which are in use at the time of inventory. A mid-size store in a city of 60k ppl.

Client came up with 5 hours - # of assets was unknown prior to project.

Thanks so much for your brain power!

Comment: Is the Client's issue the amount of time taken or is the cost more because of the more time? If the issue is the cost, find out what the client will pay, take it, and chalk this project up to a "cheap client".

Comment: Your question is unclear. You are asking for a quote but "Client is refusing to pay because it wasn't completed". What is the concrete work involved in tagging an asset ? Why do you mention "almost all of which are in use" ??

Answer (score 0):

I mean, 300 minutes, for 250 items, is a little more than 1 minute to

- fetch, access, handle the next one
- writing the information by hand or printer
- handle unexpected things
- etc.

Wishful thinking is no replacement for preparing sound specifications. Variability is an indication of low-quality, not of smartness, not of being a trustworthy client.